# How do I overload siunitx command \SI to make it appear in color everywhere?

Tags: color, siunitx

In my latex document, I have used units like:

```
\SI{100}{\eV}
```

I want to overload `\SI` such that it appears makes both arguments appear in color everywhere `\SI` is used?

Comment: What's wrong with setting `\sisetup{color = <whatever>}`?

Comment: `\sisetup{color=red}`? For more fine-grained control there are `unit-color` and `number-color`.

Comment: Do I delete the question? How can I accept comments as answers?

Comment: You just ask them to please write an answer for you to accept

Comment: @wander95:: Please don't delete the question. Since you had difficulty with it, others in the future may also have a similar issue and hence benefit from this.

Comment: Can one of the original commenters submit their comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @JosephWright Would you like to write an answer? (wander95: only you who wrote the question is notified of all comments, to notify other users write an at-sign before the username. Only one user can be notified per comment though.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `siunitx` package allows you to set color globally:

```
\sisetup{color = <whatever>}
```